# setInterval mouseout and mouseover

Tags: jquery, animation, setinterval

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer; 

    var click = function() {
        $('div button').trigger('click');
    }

    $('div button').click(function(){
        //animation
    }

    $('div').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {

        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else {
            timer = setInterval(click, 1000);

        }
    });
});
```

As you can see above, I'm trying to make a setInterval work when mouseout and stop when mouseover. The code is working at the moment, but the animation doesn't start after page load. 
So now you have to mouseover the div, mouseout and after that animation will start.
How to change it?

Comment: You could trigger the setInterval under $(document).ready and then immediately clear it.

Comment: Or just call `click()` at the end of `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add trigger after binding

```
$('div button').click(function(){
    //animation
}.trigger('click')
```